# Selenium Mocha tests on AWS ECS Docker Timeout

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, amazon-ecs

**Problem:** Selenuim Webdriver driven UI tests executing through Mocha on a NodeJS platform and running on AWS ECS are slow to the point of timing out routinely (timeout = 120000 ms, i.e. 2 minutes).

**Setup:**

1. I have a Cluster on AWS ECS. The cluster has 3 m4.xlarge instances, so CPU/Memory is NOT an issue. Additionally, the EC2 instance metrics show that even when the tests are run, the CPU/Memory Utilization is < 1%.
2. Each container is defined with the following JSON:

   `{
     "requiresAttributes": [
       {
         "value": null,
         "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18",
         "targetId": null,
         "targetType": null
       },
       {
         "value": null,
         "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth",
         "targetId": null,
         "targetType": null
       }
     ],
     "taskDefinitionArn": "someDefinition",
     "networkMode": "host",
     "status": "ACTIVE",
     "revision": 23,
     "taskRoleArn": null,
     "containerDefinitions": [
       {
         "volumesFrom": [],
         "memory": 400,
         "extraHosts": null,
         "linuxParameters": null,
         "dnsServers": null,
         "disableNetworking": null,
         "dnsSearchDomains": null,
         "portMappings": [
           {
             "hostPort": 80,
             "containerPort": 80,
             "protocol": "tcp"
           }
         ],
         "hostname": null,
         "essential": true,
         "entryPoint": [],
         "mountPoints": [
           {
             "containerPath": "/dev/shm",
             "sourceVolume": "hostDevShm",
             "readOnly": null
           }
         ],
         "name": "foo-automation-container",
         "ulimits": null,
         "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
         "environment": [],
         "links": null,
         "workingDirectory": null,
         "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
         "image": "foo-docker-container-image",
         "command": [],
         "user": null,
         "dockerLabels": null,
         "logConfiguration": null,
         "cpu": 0,
         "privileged": null,
         "memoryReservation": null
       }
     ],
     "placementConstraints": [],
     "volumes": [
       {
         "host": {
           "sourcePath": "/dev/shm"
         },
         "name": "hostDevShm"
       }
     ],
     "family": "foo-automation-tests"
   }`

**What have I tried?**

1. Apart from destroying and recreating the Cluster and Task
   Definitions numerous times, I have set up Network Mode = host, and I
   have added a volume mount based on [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#running-the-images) link.
2. I have ensured that these tests are running flawlessly (and at their
   usual speed) on containers hosted on on-premise VM's - the problem
   is just with the AWS ECS configurations.
3. I have searched for a solution to this problem for days on the web, including SO, Docker's help forums, and AWS documentation.

At this point, I have hit a wall. Any help would be most appreciated.

Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Comment: So the issue is more about browser running slow in AWS?

Comment: Effectively yes, although I would more precisely state that the time for execution of each step of a test takes exponentially longer than it does on a VM, i.e. the time each request/response takes seems to be 5-10x longer on containers.

Comment: How are you running the grid? This task looks like your task/execution code and not the grid I assume

Comment: Correct. I'm not running on Selenium grid by design, so there's no grid configuration.

Comment: So in the same container the browser also is being launched?

Comment: So your question is whether the test code and the browser live on the same container, correct? If that's the question, then yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155107/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-rubicon).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've got it running - all tests now execute at the level of performance on on-premise hardware. Here was what I did:

1. First, in your Task Definition, set Network Mode = host

In your container definition associated with the task:

1. MAKE SURE you remove all Port Mappings - leaving in port mappings interferes with the Network Mode = host setting.
2. Volume mount based on [this link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#running-the-images).
3. Set your CPU units to > 2048 (I had it at 0 based on the assumption that 0 meant unlimited CPU units).
4. Set your memory to >= 4192.
5. Most importantly, under Security, check "Privileged".

Once I did those things, the UI tests ran absolutely flawlessly and at their usual (< 1 second) speed.